# python syntax - meaning of self._setup

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to understand the following basic python syntax. Thanks in advance.

```
foo = self._setup['bar']
```

Update: fixed the typo in my earlier code segment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid Python since `python` is not a keyword:

```
>>> foo = python self._setup['bar']
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    foo = python self._setup['bar']
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Valid Python code would look like

```
foo = self._setup['bar']
```

which is constructed as follows:

```
self                     # Get the value of self (typically the current object)
self._setup              # Get the attribute "_setup" of that value
self._setup['bar']       # Get the item "bar" of the attribute value
foo = self._setup['bar'] # Assign the result to the variable foo
```

These are all very basic constructs. For details, refer to the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: Argh - fixed the typo in my question. Thanks @phihag